# Integrating smack in android

Tags: android, multithreading, chat, smack

I am trying to integrate smack API in android to make a chat application, so far i was able to use the functionality like login,register,roaster,vcard,presence,subscribe now i want to combine them all and make a chat application but i am getting confused on how to structure the app.

**Required features**

- Show list of subscribe user with their status
- update message count and notify when message received
- when user is message show to recipient if he's online
- receive message even when application is closed

**Possible Solutions**

- Now i have some option like use a service through which i handle smack call but as far i have heard service run on main thread and can block it.
- Instantiate smack API when application start and stop when application is stopped but then wont receive message when application is not active

---

So if any one can give any hint or example to structure the chat application i.e use service and a separate thread on service or an async task

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you need to use a service to handle the smack conexion. To avoid the ANR dialog, all the network operations must run in another thread. For this, you can use an `AsyncTask` (for example for the login operation) or just start a new thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
          //Your code here
          }
    }).start();
```